# Closed Ball Complete iff $(M,d)$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I encountered the following in Carothers' *Real Analysis*:

> Prove that $(M,d)$ is complete iff for each $r>0$, the closed ball $B_r=\{y\in M: d(x,y)\leq r\}$ is complete.

Attempt/Thoughts:

$(\implies)$

Suppose $M$ is complete. Let $r=\frac{1}{n}$. As $n\to\infty$, the closed ball with radius $\frac{1}{n}$ satisfies the Nested Sets Theorem. That is, $B_1\supset B_{\frac{1}{2}}\supset B_{\frac{1}{3}}\ldots$ and is non-empty. Furthermore, $\operatorname{diam}(B_{\frac{1}{n}})\to 0$. And we also note that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\neq \emptyset$. Hence it follows that $(M,d)$ is compact.

($\impliedby$)

Not too sure how to do this one, but here's what I was thinking:

Attempt:

Assume $B_r$ is complete for all $r>0$. Eventually there will be a $r$ large enough to cover the metric space. When this occurs, $M\subset B_r$, and since the closed ball was assumed to be complete, and $M$ is in $B_r$, it follows that every Cauchy sequence in $B_r$ should converge, and so every Cauchy sequence in $M$ should also converge. Hence $M$ is complete.

I don't think this is right since it assumes that $r$ has to be at a certain value before it is large enough to cover $M$, and I think I have to prove it for all $r>0$- even small $r$. Another doubt I had is that if $M$ is infinite, is it even possible to cover the whole metric space? I don't think it is, since taking $M=\mathbb{R}$ makes me think that I can never cover all of $\mathbb{R}$ since it is not bounded.

---

Any corrections/hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The forward implication can be proven much easier: a closed ball in a metric space has open complement and a closed subset of a complete space is complete.

Comment: Note sure how you get compactness above.

Comment: To do the converse, suppose $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Show that it is bounded, and hence is contained in some $r$ ball.

Comment: Regarding how I got compactness in my first proof, my book says the following are equivalent. $(1): (M,d)$ is complete. $(2):$ Every infinite, totally bounded subset of $M$ has a limit point in $M$, and $(3):$ Let $F_1\supset F_2 \supset\ldots$ be a decreasing sequence of nonempty closed sets in $M$ with $\operatorname{diam}(F_n)\to 0$. Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n\neq \emptyset$. Perhaps I misinterpreted?...

Comment: Rather than trying taking one ball that is large enough I.e. some $B_r$, take the Union over all the balls $B_r$, for example $\Bbb R=\cup_{r\gt 0}B_r(0)$

Comment: @SujaanKunalan it seems you're not entirely clear on what the forward implication says. You're asked to prove that if $(M,d)$ is complete, then all closed balls in $M$ are complete (w.r.t. the induced metric, of course). But as I noted in my comment above, that's almost trivial. Concluding that $(M,d)$ is compact is irrelevant (and almost certainly false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For the backward implication (use `\impliedby` for the correct backwards arrow) you can prove the contrapositive. Suppose $(M,d)$ is not complete and let $(x_n)$ be some non-converging Cauchy sequence in $M$. You know that $(x_n)$ is bounded, i.e. contained in some ball. Argue that such a ball cannot be complete.